# Power Automate AdaptiveCard Feed and mobile notifications only say Card

Tags: json, push-notification, microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have a Power Automate workflow that posts messages to a Teams channel. It posts to the channel correctly, but the Feed and the mobile notifications only say Card. I've tried adding the "summary": property above the body section, but that didn't do anything. I'm using the "Post card in a chat or channel" action. Is there another property that can be used?

Post a card in a chat or channel

[image]

Teams Feed notification

[image]

Comment: Currently it is not possible add summary using power automate. You can suggest this feature at https://ideas.powerautomate.com/d365community/forum/086dd68e-597f-ec11-8d21-0022482e8f9f.

Comment: Ok, I posted an idea here: https://ideas.powerautomate.com/d365community/idea/d20d68d1-5df3-ed11-a81c-6045bdb8d5bf

Comment: Is there no way to get it to show something other than "Card" on an adaptive card notification? It's irritating to have 15 notifications for different processes and they all say "Card" so we don't know what they are without clicking on them all. This makes it useless for prioritizing our responses.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible currently. As you have already submitted the idea, hopefully the feature will be made available.